# JQuery conflict with an other JQuery library

Tags: jquery, slider, conflict

I use jquery for a module. My joomla template have an integrated jquery menu. So they conflict with each other.

Is there a way to solve this problem. Following the script code of the module

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    window.onload = function () {
        var container = jQuery('div.sliderGallery');
         var ul = jQuery('ul', container);

         var itemsWidth = ul.innerWidth() - container.outerWidth();

         jQuery('.slider', container).slider({
             min: 0,
             max: itemsWidth,
             handle: '.handle',
             stop: function (event, ui) {
                 ul.animate({'left' : ui.value * -1},340);
             },
             slide: function (event, ui) {
                 ul.css('left', ui.value * -1);
             }
         });
     };
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do to fix your problem is un-alias the jQuery function and assign it to another variable name (remember: variables can be functions). You need to use the [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict) function to un-alias the `$()` function. Here one one to do it:

```
// ...after all of Joomla's JS is done executing...

// before loading your version of jQuery var jquery = {}; // aka new Object()
jquery.joomla = jQuery.noConflict(); // moves jQuery into another namespace

// load your version
```

Now, when you load your version, it will take over the jQuery and `$` namespaces, but you'll still have the other reference to Joomla's jQuery function if you need it. To re-iterate, the basic flow is:

1. Load Joomla's jQuery
2. Run Joomla's jQuery-dependent code
3. Move Joomla jQuery into another namespace
4. Load your jQuery
5. Execute your code using `$()`

Comment: "Move Joomla jQuery into another namespace" - not such a good idea, because it might run somewhere later and look for the older namepace, instead, your should rename your new jQuery instead to j$.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
var J = jQuery.noConflict();
```

after that use J variable instead of $ or jQuery for your custom code

Comment: This answer isn't good enough. you have to specify what library you want to re-map to use "J". writing this in the wrong place can result different outcomes.

Comment: i have no idea why you mean. explain.

Comment: What does the "jQuery" here come from?  How do I load (a specific version of) jQuery without polluting namespaces?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

e.g

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var container = jQuery('div.sliderGallery');
         var ul = jQuery('ul', container);

         var itemsWidth = ul.innerWidth() - container.outerWidth();
         jQuery.noConflict();
         jQuery('.slider', container).slider({
             min: 0,
             max: itemsWidth,
             handle: '.handle',
             stop: function (event, ui) {
                 ul.animate({'left' : ui.value * -1},340);
             },
             slide: function (event, ui) {
                 ul.css('left', ui.value * -1);
             }
         });
     });
</script>
```

I have updated your code to use jQuery to check for document loaded. Details for using the noConflict function is [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

Comment: I copy your code and paste it to my file but it dont change anything. Do I have to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

did you mean that your joomla loaded 2 kind of jquery at the same time ?
1st your menu load jquery
and then your module load jquery ?

here is the solutions:
In joomla templates, we can overriding the module or component views (I assume you must be using joomla 1.5.x right?)

1. in your templates create a directory called html/
   eg: templates/yourTemplate/html/
2. copy file from modules/mod_yourMenu/tmpl/.* into your your template html (templates/yourTemplate/html/mod_yourMenu/) --> * you don't need to add tmpl/ *
3. edit the php files inside and delete all 
    tag that load jquery
4. do the step 1-3 for modules that using jquery.
5. edit your template, put  tag to load latest version of jquery.

it should work now :)

Comment: hm - it might work but what if you want to use this module on many sites. I have to do this steps every time. Do you know an other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just to wrap your jq script in a self-invoking function.

```
(function($){
   $(document).ready(function(){

      $('div').click( function(){ alert('ding'); });

   });
})(jQuery);
```

This creates a private scope so you don't have to worry about any collisions.  You can skip all the uneasyness with the jQuery.noConflict(); solution and you don't have to give up that wonderful $!   I do this as a matter of habbit when I know there are other chunks of code at work (eg, any cms) - even if a new extension is added after my testing, it shouldn't break my jQuery.

There's a great overview in the jQuery Cookbook (http://listic.ru/jQuery_Cookbook.pdf - chapter 1.17).   If it's good enough for Resig, I guess it will work for me!