# Usage of jquery in joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla

I am using jquery for pagination and rokbok for popup. If I use jquery popup functionality is not working.If  I use rokbok for popup pagination is not working. I am new to this .I need both to be worked. Can anyone help me.

Comment: `is not working` is not enough to get any help. Please try to reformulate your question...

Comment: if it's just a conflict problem, you might need `jQuery.noConflict()` see here http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: It might be a conflict with two libraries, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1159900/1516616) for a possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

1. You might be having jquery conflicts.

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just
>   as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so
>   all functionality is available without using $. If we need to use
>   another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, we can return control of
>   $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict():

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict(); // OR jQuery.noConflict(); 
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

[Read More](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)

1. Check whether the required version of jquery for the plugin has been loaded properly.
2. Try to use [jQuery Easy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327). This plugin is meant to clean and prepare front and back end for the use of jQuery, alongside the Mootools libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks A lot for all who healped me. I got it by using noconflict();

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>
```

Comment: You should have posted this as a comment not an answer

Comment: I have modified the post with answer

Answer (score 0):

Sometime using noConflict might not be the best method as you will have to keep adding it to extensions you use on that page of they use jquery.

So instead, use the following code to ensure only 1 version of jquery is loaded on your page.

```
// load jQuery, if not loaded before
if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
    JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
    $document =& JFactory::getDocument();
    $document->addScript(JURI::root() . "path/goes/here/jquery-1.8.2.js");
}
```