# JQuery Menu Only Working on Homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

Alright, this is a pretty simple.. maybe even stupid question.  But I have been trying for a pretty long time to get this working properly and nothing has worked. I have a Menu that toggles with a plus / minus sign... this menu only works on the homepage though and nothing else. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('.gh-gallink').toggle(
function() {
    $('.gallery_container').animate({
        marginTop: "x",
    }, 1000);
    $('.jquerycssmenu ul li ul').animate({
        marginTop: "x",
    }, 100);
    $('.jquerycssmenu ul li ul li a').animate({
    height: "x",
    }, 100);
    $('#main').animate({
        marginTop: "x",
    }, 1000);
    $(this).text('+');


}, function() {
    $('.gallery_container').animate({
        marginTop: "x",
    }, 1000);
    $('.jquerycssmenu ul li ul').animate({
        marginTop: "x",
    }, 100);
    $('.jquerycssmenu ul li ul li a').animate({
        height: "x",
    }, 100);
    $('#main').animate({
        marginTop: "x",
    }, 1000);
    $(this).text('-');

});
});
```

The menu works fine, but again.. only on the mainpage. And of course I don't have the x's in my actual code. But anways, the code is in the header.php file of my site and again, it only works on the homepage of my site.  I tried changing the "$(document)" to "jQuery(Document)" and I also deactivated all my plugins too, but the menu still only works on the home page.

And also, here is the html that displays the toggle button:

```
<div class="gallerylink">
<a href="#" class="gh-gallink">
    -
</a>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

**Edit:**

I did what Chipmunk said and one by one got rid of each script in my header.  I found out that when I removed this script (listed below) that scrolls up the page to an achor, everything works fine.  However, I would still like to have both scripts running at the same time.  Here is the anchor scrolling script.

```
// When the Document Object Model is ready
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // 'catTopPosition' is the amount of pixels #invisiblebox
    // is from the top of the document
    var catTopPosition = jQuery('#invisiblebox').offset().top;

    // When #scroll is clicked
    jQuery('#scroll, #scrolls').click(function(){
        // Scroll down to 'catTopPosition'
        jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:catTopPosition}, 'slow');
        // Stop the link from acting like a normal anchor link
        return false;
    });
});
```

So when you click on #scrolls, or #scroll.. it scrolls back up to the anchr "#invisiblebox". I don't know why this doesn't work with my toggle menu.  If anyone has a solution to get both scripts running, please let me know.

Comment: this is probably a dumb question, but have you included jQuery on your other pages?

Comment: are you sure you have your script in the other pages as well?

Comment: @Kyle beat me to it. Check your script tags and make sure that jQuery is being loaded. Check the error console for any obvious "Unknown variable; $" that are the sign of this.

Comment: Hi Kyle, this code for the menu is in my header.php file in wordpress and the header for my website is displayed on every page. So by theory, the jquery is included on every page. Some other codes that use jquery in my header work on other pages, just not this one for the toggle menu.  I hope that helps.

Edit: OOHH I get what you mean now... and yes.. jquery is loaded in the header section of my website which loads on everypage.. again, some other jquery codes in my header work.. just not this toggle menu for some stupid reason. :(

Comment: maybe another dumb question, but are you including the script tag in the header.php or footer.php? or are you including in via wp_enqueue_script?

Comment: @bronzehedwick, im including the jquery script in my header along with my toggle navigation menu.  Other script that use jquery in my header do work, just not this one.

Comment: @user1658560 ah, beat me to the answer. It probably will not solve the problem, but fyi the proper way to to include scripts in wp is with [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Comment: Try using firebug for firefox or chrome (ctrl+shift+c) debugger to debug your webpage and check if the jquery script is actually included in all the other pages.

Comment: @Chipmunk yes it is. I checked in google chrome. :)

Comment: Okay, do you see any code like ***<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>*** in your homepage and not in any other pages?

Comment: @Chipmunk I just viewed the source for both the homepage and a page where the menu doesn't work and the header files / scripts are the exact same. :(

Comment: Could edit your question by including parts of the source which can be used to find out the problem

Comment: @Chipmunk I have about 20 scripts in my header, and I don't even know if my script is conflicting with other scripts in my header.. It would be some what messy and even pointless posting all my header scripts.

Comment: Okay no problem, use this simple method to debug, In any of your pages where the jQuery code doesnt work, strip down your header with all the scripts but the jQuery include and try reloading the page

Comment: @Chipmunk0110 I found out what the issue was.. I edited the op.  If you could help me get both scripts working together that would be awesome! :) Oh yeah.. both the toggle menu and the scroll to anchor use href"#" as links... I don't know if that would matter at all lol

Answer (score 0):

Please read 
http://www.ideazone.ca/2011/03/jquery-wordpress-how-to-avoid-common-conflicts/ and 
[JQuery conflict with an other JQuery library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159815/jquery-conflict-with-an-other-jquery-library)

Comment: That code sample and the blog post is gone. Here's a re-creation of that blog post - https://shawndewolfe.com/jquery-wordpress-how-to-avoid-common-conflicts.html