# Jquery gooey menu

Tags: jquery, menu

When i use gooeymenu.js, other jquery functions are not working, with out gooeymenu.js all functions are working fine. Please help me if any one knows about this issue. Bellow URl about gooey menu

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/gooeymenu.htm

if i use this menu bellow function are not working

```
$(".connect a").click(function () {
$(".connect_content").slideDown("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to change the jQuery alias to prevent the conflict: [JQuery conflict with an other JQuery library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159815/jquery-conflict-with-an-other-jquery-library)